How to change size of scroll content background of List in Swiftui?
I am newbie in Swift and I have a problem.
My app has 2 Lists, problem is the scroll content background creates too much space (red part in image attached), so the distance of 2 lists is so far.

How to remove this backgound or at least make it fit with the row content.
I tried
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)

but it just transparent the background, blank space still there.
Here is my code of List:
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        // HEADER
        HStack {
            // Main info
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text("Create website ABC")
            }
        }
        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.18)
        .padding(8)
        .background(
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.colorBlueStart, Color.colorBlueEnd]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
        )
        
        // DETAIL INFO
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            // List of Sessions
            List {
                Section {
                    Text("English")
                    Text("Germany")
                } header: {
                    Text("LIST 1")
                } footer: {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], -16)
            .padding(.top, -32)
            .listRowSpacing(4)
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .toolbarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .background(.red)
            
            List {
                Section {
                    Text("English")
                    Text("Germany")
                } header: {
                    Text("LIST 2")
                } footer: {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], -16)
            .padding(.top, -32)
            .listRowSpacing(4)
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .toolbarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .background(.red)
            
        }   // end VStack of DETAIL INFO
        .padding()
        .background(Color.colorGrayLight.clipShape(
            .rect(
                topLeadingRadius: 10,
                bottomLeadingRadius: 0,
                bottomTrailingRadius: 0,
                topTrailingRadius: 10
            )))
        
        Divider()
    }   // end of root VStack
    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.85)
    .background(
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.colorBlueStart, Color.colorBlueEnd]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
    )
}


Why are you putting navigation links with an empty label in your list? That is probably what causes the extra space. By the way, that way of creating navigation links is deprecated since iOS 16. What versions are you supporting?

Also, you should show a [mcve] - some code I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the issue.

My app has 2 Lists... there is only one List in the code you show, where is the other one? Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.

I edited my question, added minimal reproducible code.
@Sweeper i updated my code without navigation links, the space still exist.

Now that you added two lists, the problem is clear. It seems like you want something like this? That is, two scroll views on top of each other, that also fits its content if space allows. If you don't need them to be scrollable, see this other post.

@Sweeper sorry for late reply. Thank you for your helpful links, problem solved :)
